# Group objects by field, then group by a conditional field

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects that I'm using an ng-repeat to display.

I need to be be able to group these objects by a field, such as an departmentID.

I then need to be able to loop through each department, and then by the 2nd field, which will either be preliminary or final.  If there is a final record for a given department, the preliminary record should be hidden.  If there is no final for a given department, show the preliminary.

Ex.

- **Department 1**

  - Preliminary - not visible
- **Department 1**

  - Final - visible
- **Department 2**

  - Final - visible
- **Department 3**

  - Preliminary - not visible
- **Department 3**

  - Final - visible
- **Department 4**

  - Preliminary - visible

**Data Sample**

```js
var data = [
  { departmentID: 1, status: 'preliminary'  },
  { departmentID: 1, status: 'final'  },
  { departmentID: 2, status: 'final'  },
  { departmentID: 3, status: 'preliminary'  },
  { departmentID: 3, status: 'final'  },
  { departmentID: 4, status: 'preliminary'  },
];
```

**Current code below**

```js
if (item.result_status !== "preliminary") {
 return item;
}
else if (item.result_status === "final") {
 return item;
}
else {
 return false;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in Data | groupBy: 'department_ID'">
 <div ng-repeat="v in value | filter:prelimFilter(value)">
  <a ng-click="showPopUp(key)">{{Some Other Field}} </a>
 </div>
</div>



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: How would be the output after grouping? any example?

Comment: The expected output would look like the above section with the bold departments.  Only the ones marked as visible should appear.

Comment: In that case, just sort the array before giving it to ng-repeat, it will do the trick of grouping.

Comment: can you provide sample data please

Comment: The sample data is listed above in the bold sections.

Comment: Please share the sample json Data

Comment: See data sample above

Answer (score 0):

You are close! Your first half of the code is correct where you group the object based on `departmentID` using `groupBy` filter. The issue is with your `custom filter`. You have created a `filter function` instead of `custom filter` and the issue is `filter function` does not have access to entire array. It has access only to individual elements.  This [blog](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/#filter-4-controllerscope-filter) explains clearly the different types of `filter` that can be created in angularjs.

You can create a custom filter which has access to the array and you can return the filtered array based on status

```
.filter('myFilter', function () {  
    return function(inputArr) {
        var outputArr = [];

        outputArr = inputArr.filter(function(obj){return obj.status === "final"});

        outputArr = outputArr.filter(function(e){return e}); //To remove empty elements

        if(outputArr.length === 0){
            outputArr = inputArr; //inputArr does not have obj with status 'final'
        }

       return outputArr;
    };
});
```

Working [jsfiddle  here](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/djf6a13d/31/). Good luck!

NOTE: groupBy filter is not part of angular.js You have to include  [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#get-started) module.